# Error installing / debugging ActionScript Mobile App to phone

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash-builder, mobile-phones, flash-builder4.5

I get this error every time:

Error occurred while installing the application:
864 KB/s (33668 bytes in 0.038s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Main.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE]

I have a very simple "HelloWorld" action script mobile app which simply adds a text field to the display list.  Running the app on the desktop using the HTC Desire simulator works just fine, however testing on the device is throwing that error.

On the phone I have installed the Adobe Air available on the Market, the device is connected and the version of android running is 2.3.3.

I can't seem to get away from this error.  I've tried creating flex mobile projects and imported one of iBrent's tutorial projects ( http://www.youtube.com/user/iBrent#p/c/4/TvpvIIhvZ5s ) to see if they work but alas I get the equivalent fail error.

Any help would be appreciated with this
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you enabled USB debugging and other appropriate items on the phone?

2) Have you made sure the device is communicating with Flash Builder?

3) Can you see the device connected with the computer?

4) Have you checked the bin folder to see if an apk file was indeed created?

5) Have you set the applications manifest file appropriately?

Lots of variables here, I know, but this is a tough problem to diagnose without direct knowledge of your setup. HTH...